# Add drag and click event conflicts to elements in d3?

Tags: d3.js

Drag and click events are added to the element at d3. The first click requires that I click twice to trigger the click event. When I remove the added drag event, click once to trigger the click event.

```
d3.select('#points').append('use')
      .attr('id', 'red_'+thisId)
      .attr('class', 'point-create')
      .attr('xlink:href','#point')
      .on('click',showTipArrow)
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on('start', dragstarted)
          .on('drag', dragged)
          .on('end', dragended));

function showTipArrow(){
console.log('6666');}
```

Comment: In the react environment is abnormal, Html page inside is normal.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is when you first click, on (mousedown) the drag event starts, but only after you (mouseup), the click event loads. But as the drag event already started, the click get suppressed.

Use d3.event.defaultPrevented to control the events:

```
function showTipArrow(){
if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
console.log('6666');}
```

See this [Example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a84aeb78fea81e1ad806)